# How to generate an XML form a JSON like Ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, savon

Hi I need to generate an XML like that one below:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Addresses>
  <CurrentAddress>
   <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
   <ZipPostcode>OX4 2QX</ZipPostcode>
   <AddressLine1>36 Brasenose Driftway</AddressLine1>
   <AddressLine2>Oxford</AddressLine2>
   <AddressLine3 />
   <FirstYearOfResidence>2002</FirstYearOfResidence>
   <LastYearOfResidence>2014</LastYearOfResidence>
  </CurrentAddress>
  <PreviousAddress1>
   <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
   <ZipPostcode>AB1 1AA</ZipPostcode>
   <AddressLine1>21 A Street</AddressLine1>
   <AddressLine2>Aberdeen</AddressLine2>
   <AddressLine3 />
   <FirstYearOfResidence>1998</FirstYearOfResidence>
   <LastYearOfResidence>2002</LastYearOfResidence>
  </PreviousAddress1>
 </Addresses>
```

i.e. I need just one "Addresses" block, but I have some problem with
my current object representation:

```html
    address_count = 0
    running = []

    @person.addresses.each do |address|
      Rails.logger.debug 'Adding address'
      if address_count == 0
        Rails.logger.debug 'Adding current address'
        running.push(
            CurrentAddress: {
                Country: address.country,
                ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
                AddressLine1: address.line1,
                AddressLine2: address.line2,
                AddressLine3: address.town_city,
                FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
                LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
            }
        )
      else
        Rails.logger.debug 'Adding previous address'
        running.push(
            "PreviousAddress#{address_count}" => {
                Country: address.country,
                ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
                AddressLine1: address.line1,
                AddressLine2: address.line2,
                AddressLine3: address.town_city,
                FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
                LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
            }
        )
      end
      address_count += 1
    end
```

That in JSON will be like the code below:

```html
{
"Addresses": [
      {
        "CurrentAddress": {
          "Country": "United Kingdom",
          "ZipPostcode": "OX4 2QX",
          "AddressLine1": "36 Brasenose Driftway",
          "AddressLine2": "Oxford",
          "AddressLine3": null,
          "FirstYearOfResidence": 2002,
          "LastYearOfResidence": 2014
        }
      },
      {
        "PreviousAddress1": {
          "Country": "United Kingdom",
          "ZipPostcode": "AB1 1AA",
          "AddressLine1": "21 A Street",
          "AddressLine2": "Aberdeen",
          "AddressLine3": null,
          "FirstYearOfResidence": 1998,
          "LastYearOfResidence": 2002
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

That actually generate an XML with two "Addresses" blocks.

Someone know how I can generate a representation of my object (also if is not JSON it's ok) that after an XML conversion looks like the one I need?

I was also thinking to generate directly the XML.
In this case how I can generate the XML I need from the Ruby Hash I posted above?

Just for the record I need it because I'm working with SAVON (a SOAP client for Ruby).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

running shouldn't be an array, but a hash. This way you can associate the different addresses with different keys (CurrentAddress, PreviousAddress1 etc.)

Than at the end, you create a new hash, where you associate the whole object "running" with the key "Addresses".

```
def addresses_as_xml
  address_count = 0
  running = Hash.new

  @person.addresses.each do |address|
    if address_count == 0
      Rails.logger.debug 'Adding current address'
      running["CurrentAddress"] = {
              Country: address.country,
              ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
              AddressLine1: address.line1,
              AddressLine2: address.line2,
              AddressLine3: address.town_city,
              FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
              LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
          }
    else
      Rails.logger.debug 'Adding previous address'
      running["PreviousAddress#{address_count}"] = {
              Country: address.country,
              ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
              AddressLine1: address.line1,
              AddressLine2: address.line2,
              AddressLine3: address.town_city,
              FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
              LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
          }
    end
    address_count += 1
  end

  person_summary = {"Addresses" => running}
  person_summary.to_xml
end
```

Another remark: It seems to me that this method operates only on the addresses of a Person-object => perhaps it should be located in the model Person